# assetsLibrary a simple bug?

Tags: objective-c

I am really lost . 
why i get NSLog twice for each `UIImage` ?

```
 //------ get the images from the camera roll ----------
    assets=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *cameraRollPictures=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {

        NSInteger numberOfAssets = [group numberOfAssets];
        NSLog(@"NUM OF IMAGES:%d",numberOfAssets);
        if (numberOfAssets > 0)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfAssets-1; i++)
            {

                [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
                 {
                    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
                    [assets addObject:thumbnail];
                     NSLog(@"theObject!!!! -- (%d) %@",i,thumbnail);

            //******* for each i its here twice !!   ********

                }];
            }
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem unusual since you are enumerating possibly multiple times for each i.  In other words, if your `enumerateAssetsAtIndexes` method is called twice for each i (in your outer loop), then of course you'll get multiple NSLog() for each i.

Comment: @Jeremy: That's what I thought first, but the inner `enumerateAssetsAtIndexes` is called with an index set containing only the single index `i`, therefore each asset is enumerated only once.

Comment: I suppose I would agree if I had assurances that the usingBlock is invoked only once per index.  Apple docs mention (with regard to the usingBlock: _The block to invoke using each of the assets in the group at the indexes in indexSet._  This could be taken a couple ways I suppose, but logically, it would seem that it would fire for each asset which would cause the behavior s/he is describing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, `enumerateAssetsAtIndexes` (and `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock`) do an additional invocation of the block  with `result == nil` and `index == NSNotFound` at the end of the enumeration. This becomes obvious if you change the NSLog() to

```
NSLog(@"i=%d, index=%ld, result=%@", i, (unsigned long)index, result);
```

Then you will get the output

```
NUM OF IMAGES:2
i=0, index=0, result=ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=...
i=0, index=2147483647, result=(null)
i=1, index=1, result=ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=...
i=1, index=2147483647, result=(null)
```

Therefore you have to check the value of `result` and ignore a `nil` value:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfAssets-1; i++) {
     [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
      {
          if (result != nil) {
              UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
              [assets addObject:thumbnail];
          }
      }];
}
```

Note that you can simplify the enumeration to

```
[group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
     if (result != nil) {
         UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
         [assets addObject:thumbnail];
     }
}];
```