# Cant stop NSAssetsLibrary

Tags: objective-c

It is working good but its not stops.

```
         [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:set options:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
          {
              CGImageRef imageRef = result.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage;
              UIImage *toSend=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

              NSLog(@"INDEXX:%d",index); //logged after i stop !

              for(int c=0;c<[selectedButtonsTags count];c++)
                  if((numberOfAssets-1)-index ==[[selectedButtonsTags objectAtIndex:c] integerValue])
                  {[savedImages addObject:toSend];   NSLog(@"IMAGE IS:%@ index:%d",toSend,index); }


              if(index==numberOfAssets-max-1 )
              {   NSLog(@"OUT!");   //it DO log this !
                   *stop=YES;  
              }


          }];
```

After it logs `OUT` , it logs again `index:`garbage number`

Comment: You have to check for `result == nil` or `index == NSNotFound` in the block, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096662/assetslibrary-a-simple-bug for a very similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to understand how it works.
if i do things in the block before i stop him , he continue to enumerate and when i stop him he already started the next index .

so you have to stop him right when the block starts before doing more things.

```
          if(index==numberOfAssets-max-1 )
              *stop=YES;
```

is now at the start of the block, and he DO stops.
If one's need to later call a function , you can than put the same condition later one.
But , you have to stop him first as i said .